# Does OpenVPN work on Ubuntu 16.04 for internet browsing in China?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am moving to China and I'd like to be able to enjoy all the banned sites there. Can someone confirm if OpenVPN does the trick?

Cheers

Comment: It appears you have to do some work to mask the fact that it's an OpenVPN connection: https://greycoder.com/openvpn-china/